# Ansible Search, Copy and Exclude

Tags: ansible

I have a ton of directories that are missing a file. The objective is to scan the entire directory list for example `/path/to/directories/*` and if there is a directory that is missing a specific file, it should be copied over. If it already has it ignore it. I also need to exclude some directories within that search.

I know I can use the "stat" command in ansible to check for the files possibly in a loop "with_items" since it's going to be a bunch of directories maybe a wild card can be used?

I know I can use the copy command but I'm not 100% sure how to put it all together.

Is it possible to use a wildcard for the following:

```
tasks:
  - name: Check to see if file exists
  stat:
    path: {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - /root/recursive/repos/*/layers/*/images/blank.jpg
  Register: stat_result
```

Would I have to add each directory path? Is there also a way to pass the info generated from one task to another so which ever directory it files without the file in the copy step it can just copy the file to which ever directory is missing it?

```
- name: Copy the file is it doesn't exists
    copy:
      src: blank.jpg
      dest: /root/recursive/repos/*/layers/*/images/blank.jpg
    when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
```

In the first step, is there a way to exclude certain directories so it can search all except directories with "name" in it? I believe I can also use the synchronize option also?

```
- name: Synchronize passing in extra rsync options
    synchronize:
      src: blank.jpg
      dest: /root/recursive/repos/*/layers/*/images
      rsync_opts:
        - "dir1"
        - "dir2"
        - "dir3"
```

Sorry for all these questions and thank you for any and all help.

Thank You

Comment: As correctly pointed out by @Vladimir Botka in his answer, the `copy` module is idempotent (so is `synchronize`). Ideally you can have just one task and "define" what file(s) target location should have, without the need to search/exclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither *find* nor *stat* module will help you here, I think. You'll have to list the directories from the command line. For example, given the tree

```sh
shell> tree /tmp/recursive
/tmp/recursive
├── A
│   └── layers
│       ├── 1
│       │   └── images
│       │       └── blank.jpg
│       └── 2
│           └── images
└── B
    └── layers
        ├── 1
        │   └── images
        │       └── blank.jpg
        └── 2
            └── images
```

the tasks below

```yaml
    - command:
        cmd: bash -c 'ls -1d /tmp/recursive/*/layers/*/images'
      register: result
    - copy:
        src: blank.jpg
        dest: "{{ item }}/blank.jpg"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

read the directories and copy the missing files only

```yaml
TASK [command] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [copy] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/A/layers/1/images)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/A/layers/2/images)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/B/layers/1/images)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/B/layers/2/images)
```

As a result, the file is present in all directories

```sh
shell> tree /tmp/recursive
/tmp/recursive
├── A
│   └── layers
│       ├── 1
│       │   └── images
│       │       └── blank.jpg
│       └── 2
│           └── images
│               └── blank.jpg
└── B
    └── layers
        ├── 1
        │   └── images
        │       └── blank.jpg
        └── 2
            └── images
                └── blank.jpg
```

The *copy* task is idempotent. All items are reported OK if you run it again

```yaml
TASK [copy] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/A/layers/1/images)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/A/layers/2/images)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/B/layers/1/images)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/recursive/B/layers/2/images)
```

Comment: Hello, I took your suggestion and came up with the following:

https://pastebin.com/z8N1ZY5x

It worked perfectly. It allowed me to find a list of directories that did not contain the file and also exclude some directories as well, turned it into a list and after added the file in the directories that did not have it and delete the file in any directory that didn't require it. Thank you again for your help!!